# where to find corrosive weapons in borderlands 2 easy?

Tags: borderlands-2

i am a level 12 commando (heavy shock trooper) on borderlands 2. I'm on the dam fine rescue mission and need to beat w4r d3n but i can't find any corrosive weapons. i heard there are some hidden in certain chests and in shops but i can't find any. any help or corrosive weapon locations?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that all weapons are completely ranomized, there is no "easy" way to find one. The only way to specificly get one would either be to get a Unique one (usally from quests, has red under text and interesting title). They have much less RNG put into them, and some have a 100% chance to be Corrosive.

But, your best bet would be to just play the game. If you need a Corrosive weapon to beat W4R-D3N, you could easily go raid some Bandit camps for chests and drops, and just keep doing that until you get one. Also, as said in the other answer, you can (and should) check out all of Marcus' Weapon Vending Machines. They sell random weapons, and one of the weapons in it could be one with a Corrosive element.

Answer (score 0):

just go to different weapon vending machines and find one. if you can't they have new weapons daily.

Comment: they have new weapons twentyminutely, to be exact.